# When to use :grep and :vimgrep in vim?

Tags: command-line, search

In vim `:make` makes it easy to build and fix errors, and `:grep` and `:vimgrep` behaves like `:make`.  But why do you need these two commands? Why not just search for the pattern and just press `n`? What are the advantages of them over just searching?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the doc say:

```
Vim has two ways to find matches for a pattern: Internal and external.
```

In a nutshell, `:vimgrep` uses Vim's grep mechanism to read and find in files. `:grep` uses an external commands to achieve the same job.

The `/` search is for the current buffer only, whereas `:[vim]grep` search through a pattern of files, allowing you to search in an entire project at once.

Have a look at `:h grep` for more information.

Answer (score 7):

One benefit of `:[vim]grep` over `/?` is that the results get put into the quickfix list (or location list if you use `:l[vim]grep`), this means that you can pull up a list of all matches using `:cl`. You can then use a number to go directly to the result you want from the list.

It also means that you can use the same command for searching the current buffer `:[vim]grep pattern %` as for searching your entire code base `:[vim]grep pattern path` so there's some nice symmetry to it.

Further to this you can then branch out and use the [Silver Surfer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) / [Ripgrep](https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep) to give you very powerful searching. These can be mapped to the `:[vim]grep` command.

Answer (score 4):

`/?` only search the current buffer but `:grep` and `:vimgrep` take arbitrary files/patterns/globs as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 primary advantages I see

1. **Use a consistent `regex` engine/syntax:** Using `:grep/vimgrep` allows you to define a `grepprg`, which can be defined to `grep/ack/ag` etc. Using this you can search the current buffer or multiple buffers/files, using a consistent `regex` engine. On the other hand, if you use *vim’s*`/pattern` option, you are stuck on vim’s default regex engine, which has a different syntax compared to `extended regular expression` syntax. So, anytime you have to search for an expression, you will have to think/remember whether you should use `\)` or just `)` and other differences. This can be very annoying (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864467/whats-the-difference-between-vim-regex-and-normal-regex)
2. **vimgrep populates a quickfix/location list**: using `:grep/vimgrep` allows you to populate a search list. (https://medium.com/@lakshmankumar12/quickfix-and-location-list-in-vim-ca0292ac894d).

   If you do want to use the location list, you can use `]q` shortcut to navigate it if you have Tim-Popes unimpaired plugin (https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)
3. **complicated searches while within vim**: typically if you have to do complicated searches you may have to use the command line. However, if you define the `greprg` properly and use a command such as [1]

   :vim /pattern1/ `find . -type f`

   You can do very complicated searches and display the search results in your `location list` or `quickfix list`.

[1] http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/